# AG Grid / Angular 6 - trying to render a hyperlink with two columns

Tags: hyperlink, angular6, ag-grid

I'm trying to do this in my AG Grid (Angular 6):

- have a column that **shows** the name of my object
- but at the same time, that column should render this as a hyperlink to an edit page, using the **Id** of that object (not the name)

My current code snippet:

```
columnDefs = [
    { 
        headerName: 'Name', field: 'Name', width: 125,
        cellRenderer: function(params) {
             return '<a href="/admin/edit/' + params.value + '">' + params.value + '</a>';
        }
    },
```

However, right now, all I can do is create a cell renderer, but since it's the cell renderer for the column of the `Name` column, I can only access that name - but I need the `Id` to build the hyperlink, which should point to `/admin/edit/47` (or whatever the `Id` might be).

How can I accomplish this? What more do I need to do in order to be able to get both the `Name` (for display) as well as the `Id` in my cell renderer?

Comment: not the first time you forget that `params` has `data` - which represent full data for that row (in `cellRenderer` case)

Comment: @un.spike: indeed! Guess I need to put this down on a post-it attached to my screen, in order not to forget yet another time  ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it using `params.data.Id` where `params.data` points to your object bound to your record. So,

```
cellRenderer: function(params) {
  return '<a href="/admin/edit/' + params.data.Id + '">' + params.value + '</a>';
}
```

will give you the result you are expecting.

Comment: Causes a complete page refresh. This isn't great in a SPA!

Comment: have you heard about `LocationStrategy` in [tag:angular]? you can include `#` in the `a` tag if you want.. depends on routing system of your app.